# Text color of default console window

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the default color of text appearing on the console window ? It is not pure white, but it is some shade of white. Can I use this color for Rich Textbox text ?

Answer (score 6):

Default Color is based on the MSDN documentation `System.ConsoleColor.Gray`. Seems to be true. A test line compared to the default cmd prompt looks identical.
The colors are the same like the [Color-Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189018.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You may write couple of lines of code know default value.

```
Console.ResetColor();
Console.WriteLine(Console.ForegroundColor);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the color code of the console text color in the console properties.

- Open a command prompt
- Click on the icon located in top left corner
- Select "Properties" from the context menu
- Goto "Colors" Tab
- Select "Screen Text" radio button

You'll see the color in the textboxes shows the RGB values. In my machine it happens to be R-192,G-192,B-192

[image: Command Properties]

Answer (score 1):

As an extra-info you can also control the formatting and colours using shell-codes e.g. write this code to console: `^[4;38m`. Will set colour to grey and underlined. This can be especially useful for Linux console (which support additional italic(3) and darker-text(2)):

A script to print colours and formatting.

```vbnet
Dim ShellCode As String
Dim ConColer As ConsoleColor
Dim ResetCodeShell = ChrW(27) & "[0;0m"

Console.WriteLine("Colors using .Net ConsoleColor enum:")
For i As Integer = 0 To 15
    ConColer = CType(i, ConsoleColor)
    Console.Write(ConColer.ToString.PadRight(25))
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConColer
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World! (#" & i.ToString & ")")
    Console.ResetColor()
Next
Console.ResetColor()
Console.WriteLine("Default ForegrundColor: " & Console.ForegroundColor.ToString & "(#" & DirectCast(Console.ForegroundColor, Integer).ToString & ")" & vbLf)

Console.WriteLine("Colors using shell code:")
For ColorCode As Integer = 30 To 48
    For Each FormatCode As String In {"0", "4", "1", "7"} '{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"}
        ShellCode = ChrW(27) & "[" & FormatCode & ";" & ColorCode.ToString & "m"
        Console.WriteLine("Color-code:" & ColorCode.ToString & " / Format-code:" & FormatCode.ToString & " / Shellcode:" & ShellCode.Replace(ChrW(27), "^") & " / Result: " & ShellCode & "Hello World! @@@@" & ResetCodeShell)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

*vb.net*

Result:

[image]